Short story set on a generational ship in which the hero/villain has a device that enables him to run away from his enemies or desperate situations
I am searching for an old Sci-Fi short story, which my mother told me about.
According to her, it was in a Sci-Fi anthology, and it must have been written (or published?) approximately in the 60s-70s, the time she thinks of as "the Golden Age".
The story is about a generational ship, and they seem to have political conflict in the ship due to a long and stressful journey.
The hero (or the main villain) seems to get hold of some kind of device, which can either "make a pocket dimension" or enable him to "skip time", so that he could run away from his enemies or desperate situations.
However, his secret (his power or device) was somehow noticed by his enemies, perhaps because he always put his hand in his pocket, and they shot him just before he pushed the button. He was killed and his body went into another space, and the story ended with a phrase like "and there he hung, as dead as a man would ever be".
I asked this on another site, but nobody has answered the question yet.
I know many details are vague, yet I would appreciate if anyone could possibly tell me the title and/or author of this story.

Hi. Can you clarify whether this is a short story or a novel, as you've used both terms in this question?

Thank you for your reply. Actually, it seems to be a short story from a book. Sorry about my confusing words.
